How to rotate a triangle to get this picture?
Based on this answer, I am trying to draw the picture b).

I tried
Clear["Global`*"];
a = {0, 0};
b = {4, 0};
c = {4, 2};
reg = Polygon[{a, b, c}];
g = RegionCentroid[reg];
line = InfiniteLine[{b, a}];
h = RegionNearest[line, g];
RegionDistance[line, g];
RegionPlot[reg, Epilog -> {Red, line, Point[g], Blue, Arrow[{g, h}]}, 
 AspectRatio -> Automatic]
Integrate[2  \[Pi]*RegionDistance[line, {x, y}], {x, y} \[Element] reg]
Needs["OpenCascadeLink`"];
poly2d = reg;
{aa, bb, cc} = PadRight[#, 3] & /@ {a, b, c};
poly3d = Polygon[{aa, bb, cc}];
shape = OpenCascadeShape[poly3d];
sweep = OpenCascadeShapeRotationalSweep[shape, {aa, bb}, 2   \[Pi]];
bmesh = OpenCascadeShapeSurfaceMeshToBoundaryMesh[sweep, 
   "ShapeSurfaceMeshOptions" -> {"AngularDeflection" -> 0.1}];
breg = BoundaryMeshRegion[bmesh];
Show[bmesh[
  "Wireframe"[
   "MeshElementStyle" -> 
    Directive[FaceForm[Directive@{Opacity[.5], Cyan}], EdgeForm[]], 
   Lighting -> "ThreePoint"]], Graphics3D[{Red, poly3d}]]

and got


I also tried
Needs["OpenCascadeLink`"];
poly2d = 
  Polygon@MeshPrimitives[
      BoundaryDiscretizeRegion@
       ImplicitRegion[{0 <= y <= x/2, 0 <= x <= 4}, {x, y}], 1][[;; , 
      1]][[;; , 1]];
poly3d = RegionProduct[poly2d, Point[{0}]];
shape = OpenCascadeShape[poly3d];
sweep = OpenCascadeShapeRotationalSweep[
   shape, {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0} + {1, 0, 0}}, 2  \[Pi]];
bmesh = OpenCascadeShapeSurfaceMeshToBoundaryMesh[sweep, 
   "ShapeSurfaceMeshOptions" -> {"AngularDeflection" -> 0.1}];
reg = BoundaryMeshRegion[bmesh];
bmesh["Wireframe"[
  "MeshElementStyle" -> Directive[FaceForm[Cyan], EdgeForm[]], 
  Lighting -> "ThreePoint"]]

and got


A starting point.
Clear["Global`*"];
f[x_] := x/2;
plot1 = RevolutionPlot3D[{x, f[x]}, {x, 0, 4}, 
   RevolutionAxis -> {1, 0, 0}, 
   PlotStyle -> Directive@{Opacity[.2], GrayLevel[.1]}, 
   PlotPoints -> 60, MaxRecursion -> 2, Mesh -> None, Axes -> False, 
   Boxed -> False];
plot2 = RevolutionPlot3D[{3, y}, {y, 0, f[3]}, 
   RevolutionAxis -> {1, 0, 0}, PlotStyle -> GrayLevel[.9], 
   MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, Mesh -> 30];
{a, b, c} = {{0, 0, f[0]}, {4, 0, 0}, {4, 0, f[4]}};
g1 = Graphics3D[{Blue, Arrow@Tube@{{0, 0, 0}, {5.5, 0, 0}}, 
    EdgeForm[Thick], FaceForm[Directive@{Opacity[.2], Glow@Yellow}], 
    Triangle[{a, b, c}]}, Lighting -> "ThreePoint"];
Show[plot1, plot2, g1, PlotRange -> All]



Graphics3D[{Arrowheads[Medium], Arrow[{{0,0,0},{6,0,0}}], 
  Arrow[Prepend[5] /@ Most[CirclePoints[{1/3,Pi/8}, 50]]], 
  FaceForm[Opacity[.8, Yellow]], Polygon[{{0, 0, 0}, {4, 0, 0}, {4, 0, 2}}],
  FaceForm[Opacity[.5, LightGray]], EdgeForm[], Cone[{{4, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}, 2],
  Dashed, Line[Prepend[4] /@ CirclePoints[2, 50]], 
  Line[Prepend[2] /@ CirclePoints[50]], 
  Texture[Rasterize[Graphics[{HatchFilling[Pi/4,3,20], Rectangle[]}]]],
  Polygon[Prepend[2] /@ CirclePoints[50]]}, 
 Lighting -> "ThreePoint", 
 Boxed -> False, 
 ImageSize -> Large, 
 Axes -> False] 



Graphics[{Arrowheads[Medium], 
  Arrow @ Circle[{5, 0}, {1/8, 1/2}, {-2 Pi + Pi/3, Pi/4}], 
  LightGray, EdgeForm[], Polygon[{{0, 0}, {4, 0}, {4, -2}}], 
  Opacity[1], Disk[{4, 0}, {1/2, 2}], 
  EdgeForm[{Dashing[{}], Black, Thick}], Opacity[.5], Yellow, 
  Polygon[{{0, 0}, {4, 0}, {4, 2}}],  
  EdgeForm[{Dashed, Thin}], Gray, 
  {HatchFilling[], Disk[{2, 0}, {1/4, 1}]}, Disk[{4, 0}, {1/2, 2}], 
  Opacity[1], Black, Dashed, 
  Line[{{2, 0}, {2, 1}}], Text[Style["D", 20, Italic], {4/3, 1/3}], 
  Text[Style["S(x)", 20, Italic], {7/3, -3/2}], Dashing[{}], 
  Arrow[BezierCurve[{{7/3, -4/3}, {7/3, -1}, {7/3, -1/2}, {2, -1/2}}]]},
 PlotRange -> {{-.25, 6}, All}, 
 Axes -> {True, False}, 
 Ticks -> {Thread[{{0, 2, 4}, {0, x, 4}}], None}, 
 AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[Medium], 
 AxesLabel -> {"x", None}, 
 LabelStyle -> 20, ImageSize -> Large]


